# Reframing a square according to a model with openCV/C++

Tags: c++, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkevW.jpg)I already have posted this question but I will try to be more specific this time.

I'm able to detect a square with the original opencv's method :

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int thresh = 50, N = 11;
const char* wndname = "Square Detection Demo";

static double angle( Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
    double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}
static void findSquares( const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    squares.clear();
    Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

    pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
    pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;
            }
            findContours(gray, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            vector<Point> approx;

            for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {

                approxPolyDP(contours[i], approx, arcLength(contours[i], true)*0.02, true);

                if( approx.size() == 4 &&
                    fabs(contourArea(approx)) > 1000 &&
                    isContourConvex(approx) )
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;
                    for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                    {
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    if( maxCosine < 0.0595) // 0.0595
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
static void drawSquares( Mat& image, const vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++ )
    {
        const Point* p = &squares[i][0];
        int n = (int)squares[i].size();
        polylines(image, &p, &n, 1, true, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, LINE_AA);
    }
    imshow(wndname, image);
}

int main(void)
{
    static const char* names[] = { /*"C:\\Users\\hugoo\\Documents\\Prog\\NexterMU\\Qt\\OpenCV\\DetectionShapeProgram\\square_01.jpg ",
                                   "C:\\Users\\hugoo\\Documents\\Prog\\NexterMU\\Qt\\OpenCV\\DetectionShapeProgram\\square_02.png ",*/
                                   "C:\\Users\\hugoo\\Documents\\Prog\\NexterMU\\Qt\\OpenCV\\DetectionShapeProgram\\IMG_0480.jpg ",
                                   0 };

    vector<vector<Point> > squares;

    for( int i = 0; names[i] != 0; i++ )
    {
        string filename = samples::findFile(names[i]);
        Mat image = imread(filename, IMREAD_COLOR);
        if( image.empty() )
        {
            cout << "Couldn't load " << filename << endl;
            continue;
        }
        findSquares(image, squares);
        drawSquares(image, squares);
        int c = waitKey();
        if( c == 27 )
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But now what I want to do is reframing the given square detected by this program and reframing/flatennig it with a model (square) that already exists.

The reason I want to that is because when the user is gonna take a photo of a square he will maybe not be just right above the square but maybe a little bit on the right/left side of it.

In my mind it is kind of "moving" the camera right up above the square. So every shapes I need to analyse inside the given square will not be distorted.

According to that, maybe some of you have already done this kind of thing before. I hope you'll be able to give me the tools I need to do that. I thank you for that in advance.

I'm sure there is some opencv functions that could help. I just don't know them yet. I will keep searching.

I can't really say more about why I do this, but if you have any questions that could help you helping me, I'm all ears. I'm kind of stuck right now ;).

Thank you again.

Input image : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkevW.jpg)
Reference image : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3nzk.jpg)

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/

Comment: It would be great to see input and desired output images.

Comment: Ok, thank you I'll look at this. I'll keep you posted